# Can you hide an embedded you tube video but still play audio?

Tags: html, youtube

I have a page on my site where users can ember youtube videos with the typical

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T3kCQpX0H8E?autoplay=1"frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and most users use this to autoplay a song on their page when another user visits. Is there a way to hide the video though, where the audio plays and not the video. i would like to make my site easier for mobile devices by not displaying videos like that when a user visits since some users have complained that it cuts into their data

Comment: it deleted the embed code :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround, nonetheless the best of the practices for DOM manipulation would be to basically hide this frame by leaving its height and width to 1px and its opacity to zero. Again, I don't consider this is a good practice but it will do the job. Make sure the autoplay is set on the YouTube Frame parameters in order to work as well. I hope this helps you with your task, mate!

```css
.hiddenFrame{
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
    opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>hiddenIFrame</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="hiddenFrame" width="560" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T3kCQpX0H8E?autoplay=1"frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those are fantastic news, pal, glad to read these lines.

You may now accept the answer as correct if you believe is the best solution to your problem. That way other people can see that this problem is solved. If not, you can simply wait until someone else gives you a better solution. 

Cheers mate!